# Configure Oracle .Net Framework Data Provider for NPoco

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, npoco

NPoco should work for Oracle database out of the box.
But when I try to create the Database object it says it cannot find the .Net Framework Data provider:

```
        _db = new Database("connectionStringName");
```

I suspect there's some sort of configuration I need to do. But can't find how to do this in the documentation or any Nuget packages that might do it.

Full error message:

```
System.ArgumentException: System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed..
Result StackTrace:  
at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)
   at NPoco.Database..ctor(String connectionStringName, Nullable`1 isolationLevel, Boolean enableAutoSelect)
   at NPoco.Database..ctor(String connectionStringName, Boolean enableAutoSelect)
   at NPoco.Database..ctor(String connectionStringName)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to install the following NuGet package: Official Oracle ODP.NET Managed Driver